# Creating a Live CD with Gnome-Classic as default environment?

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic, live-environment

I'm not sure if this will fit into the categories of other questions on here; if it does, please lead me to the right post?

I want to create a 12.04 Live CD that, instead of having Unity (`ubuntu`) installed, has Gnome Classic (`gnome-session-fallback`) as the only desktop environment? I want to compile this for people that I know that would be more comfortable trying (and hopefully switching to) Ubuntu but would not like the Unity shell. I want to have a Live CD ready for those people so that they won't have to install it, add Gnome Classic, then try to see if they like it.

Is this possible, and if so, does it requiring compiling a CD from the source?

Edit: Rather than limiting this to Live CD, I want to do this for a Live .iso so it can be done on CD/DVD/USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

However, I would do this in the following way to avoid those command line hurdle.

- Install ubuntu in virtualbox.
- Install `gnome-classic` and remove unity. Also you can install softwares required like vlc,mp3 codecs.
- Use [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.org) to create an live image.

Comment: Looks like this will work! I need to tinker around with it, but this is exactly what I need.